# Visual Studio debugger, symbols not loaded when w3wp is launched by an ASP Classic page

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, dll, debug-symbols

I am having difficulty attaching the Visual Studio debugger to the IIS w3wp process.  In certain repeatable circumstances, I am finding that symbols do not appear to be loaded based on how the w3wp process is launched.

**For example:**

- Recycling the app pool and loading any aspx page first from any .NET project results in the debugger working just fine, and my breakpoints are hit.
- Recycling the app pool and loading any ASP Classic page first, results in symbols not being loaded, even if I subsequently load to an aspx page before attaching to the process.

I think it might be something to do with the way Visual Studio automatically determines which code types to debug, but I don't know enough about this to be sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When you debug - do you deploy the same application version to your IIS?

I believe that by default in VS settings (Tools -> Options -> Debugging) an option "Require source files to exactly match the original version" is enabled, try to disable it.

Comment: Yes - I'm confident the code is exactly the same.  Also in the examples I mention above, I am not modifying the code at all.

Thank for your suggestion, but symbols are still not loaded when the w3wp process is initialised by loading an ASP Classic page